# Defined width div causing page to scroll horizontally

Tags: html, css

This div below is causing the page to scroll horizontally on smaller then 1450px browsers. I thought overflow would fix this issue, but does not appear to... may be something I need to do on the parent div's. Any ideas?

http://barr-display.mybigcommerce.com/

```
   #Header {
    position: relative;
    clear: both;
    width: 1450px;
    min-height: 190px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: url('/content/headerbg3.jpg') repeat-x;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On body you need the following

```
body {
  width:100%;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

The reason your code is not working is that you're setting `overflow` on the child(`#header`) when it needs to be set on the parent.

Answer (score 0):

Add these lines to your css:

```
html, body {
    width:100%;
}
body {
    overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

You need `overflow-x` so the vertical scroll bar doesn't disappear.
Also, remove `overflow: hidden;` from the `#Header`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want three things:

1. No scrollbar when header image is cut off.
2. YES to scrollbars when main page content is cut off.
3. Ability for your header background to extend to the right if the browser window is wide.

You really needed to post more of the relevant code here. However, I look at your site, and this'll fix it:

1. Change your rule for #outer:

`#Outer {
  clear: both;
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-height: 190px;
  width: 1024px;
}`

1. Remove the margin and width rules from #outer's parent, and replace with `width:100%;overflow-x:hidden;`